# NativeAzureFileSystem.delete with recursive = true failed on none-empty folder

Tags: java, azure-storage

My configuration is working with many other operations including of empty folder. So it is not a config issue.
I'm running the latest version hadoop-azure-3.3.6.jar
Any suggestions on deleting none empty folder? I cannot implement the recursion version myself, as this delete method is also called from many Spark functions.

```
//<container-name>,<storage-account> replaced with my values
Path src = new Path("wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/");
FileSystem fs = src.getFileSystem(jsc.hadoopConfiguration());
fs.delete(src, true);
```

```
This failed with error:
org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.delete(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.delete(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.deleteFile(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$2.execute(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor.executeParallel(AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.deleteWithoutAuth(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.delete(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.delete(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1977)
```

Many people are asking about the same error but with different scenarios with no answer. I think it may be a bug in the library.

Comment: Update: I asked the same question on Azure and they said they are looking into it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1421127/nativeazurefilesystem-delete-with-recursive-true-f?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1360372

Answer (score 2):

I added some code to handle the exception and was able to delete the blobs in a directory from the storage container.

**Code :**

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AzureFileSystemExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String containerName = "<container_name>";
            String storageAccount = "<storage_name>";
            String storageAccountKey = "<storage_key>"; 
            String basePath = "wasbs://" + containerName + "@" + storageAccount + ".blob.core.windows.net/";

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.set("fs.azure.account.key." + storageAccount + ".blob.core.windows.net", storageAccountKey);

            Path src = new Path(basePath);

            FileSystem fs = src.getFileSystem(conf);

            deleteRecursive(fs, src);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void deleteRecursive(FileSystem fs, Path path) throws IOException {
        if (fs.isDirectory(path)) {
            FileStatus[] fileStatuses = fs.listStatus(path);
            for (FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatuses) {
                deleteRecursive(fs, fileStatus.getPath());
            }
        }

        Path parentPath = path.getParent();
        if (parentPath != null) {
            fs.delete(path, false);
            System.out.println("Deleted: " + path);
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml :**

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Output :**

It runs successfully and deletes the blobs in a directory from the storage container as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code, I can see that will work if I'm calling the delete function myself.
But as I mentioned in my question "I cannot implement the recursion version myself, as this delete method is also called from many Spark functions."